# Printer reverts to being disabled?

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, printing, printer

I have a Brother HL-L8260CDW printer connected via USB to a machine running Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon.

The printer works fine -- however after a time period it becomes "unplugged".

In order to get it to work again I have to go to Printer Properties -> Policies and click "Enabled."

Any idea why this is happening and how I can stop the printer from being "Disabled" automatically?

I had previously used this printer on Linux Mint 17.2 MATE with no problems.

Comment: Will most probably be a driver issue

Comment: I'm using the same driver as I did on the Mint 17.2 MATE install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a great solution, but based on a suggestion here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/23503/network-printer-gets-disabled-occasionally

I just added a cronjob to re-enable the printer every minute:

```
 */1 * * * * /usr/sbin/cupsenable Brother-HL-L8360CDW-series
```

Solves the annoyance at least, if not the underlying problem.